401 while sending request from RestClient with proxy
I'm trying to send POST request to some API but facing the issue with authorization when I'm trying to send this request from RestClient. Meanwhile, everything is fine with sending it through PowerShell or Postman.
The authorization data is equal in all cases, but I still somehow am not able to authorize.
Headers of request made from PowerShell - successful response

Headers of request made from RestClient - unauthorized

Here's how I initialize RestClient:
private RestClient InitializeHttpClient()
{
    var proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    var clientOptions = new RestClientOptions()
    {
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password, Encoding.ASCII),
        Expect100Continue = false,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None,
        BaseUrl = new Uri(baseUrl),
        Proxy = proxy
    };

    return new RestClient(clientOptions);
}

